# Hotkey issues for deselect

Tags: modeling

I tried everything that I know to do but for some reason, out of nowhere, my deselect all "a" key will not deselect. I have to Shift+B to deselect all. I have a brand new computer and the deselect was working fine last week. I tried loading the factory settings from the file menu but same thing. I do not know anything about scripting so I wouldn't know where to begin. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked into the Preferences > Input > 3D View > Object Mode > (De)select All, and change the shortcut back to A if it's not, then Save User Settings

Comment: Yes, it is labeld as A as well as double click. I didn't know about the double click but the "a" still does not deselect

Comment: What version of Blender? Where do you install it from? Also did you check the A key works in other programs?

Comment: Are you using an off-brand version of blender, such as "blender for artists" or the included maya/max layouts?

Comment: @MrZak I am using 2.79b installed from www.blender.org, The A key works everywhere except to deselect all

Comment: @Kirbinator, all I know is that I went to www.blender.org and clicked download

Comment: Have you installed any addons, updated drivers in last week. Does this happen in default file after "Restore Factory Settings"?

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall The Blender 2.79b Then Reinstall It . If the problem still occurs try installing the blender 2.79a version of it.
HAPPY BLENDING

Comment: Got questions. Ask me

Comment: ... and if the problem still occurs?  Reinstalling software IMO should be a last resort workaround.

Comment: yes. but the another version of 2.79